# Dynamic heading text based upon selected link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a portfolio site set up and I have my portfolio set up to shuffle through by selecting certain filters. What I want to do is set some header text, based upon which filter they choose.

The issues is when I select a link, let's say advertising, Advertising will show up as my header text. However if I select something else, say branding, it doesn't change, it stays at advertising.

here is my html

```
<div id="portfolio-filter-container">
            <h2 class="workFilterSelect">FILTER OPTIONS: <span class="currentFilter">ALL</span></h2>
        </div>
        <ul id="portfolio-filter">
            <!--<li class="workFilterSelect">FILTER OPTIONS:</li>-->
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#all" title="all">All</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#ad" title="advertising" rel="ad">Advertising</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#brand" title="" rel="brand">Branding</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#catalog" title="" rel="catalog">Catalog</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#id" title="" rel="id">Corporate ID</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#relations" title="" rel="relations">Consumer Relations</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#incentive" title="" rel="incentive">Incentive/Loyalty</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#packaging" title="" rel="packaging">Packaging</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#launch" title="" rel="launch">Product Launch</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#promo" title="" rel="promo">Promotion</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#public" title="" rel="public">Public Relations</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#sales" title="" rel="sales">Sales Support</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#social" title="" rel="social">Social Media</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#trade" title="" rel="trade">Tradeshows</a></li>
            <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#web" title="" rel="web">Web/Mobile</a></li>
            </ul>
    <div id="bottomWrapper">
```

and here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".workFilterButtons a").click(function(){
        $(".currentFilter").replaceWith($(this).append());
    }); 
});
```

by default the page is set to "ALL" when loaded, but as you can see I am trying to gett he dynamic text to work within the .currentFilter span

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want text you use `text()` method to both `get` and `set`. Also you don't want to replace the element or it won't be found again because it will no longer exist

Try

```
$(".workFilterButtons a").click(function(){
    $(".currentFilter").text($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to replace the element with the clicked `<a>` element (unless you really want to), all you need to do is update the text:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".workFilterButtons a").click(function () {

        // selecting the element with the class
        // of 'currentFilter', and setting its
        // text (using the text() method) to
        // the textContent of the clicked <a>
        // element:
        $(".currentFilter").text(this.textContent);
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".workFilterButtons a").click(function() {
    $(".currentFilter").text(this.textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="portfolio-filter-container">
  <h2 class="workFilterSelect">FILTER OPTIONS: <span class="currentFilter">ALL</span></h2>

</div>
<ul id="portfolio-filter">
  <!--<li class="workFilterSelect">FILTER OPTIONS:</li>-->
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#all" title="all">All</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#ad" title="advertising" rel="ad">Advertising</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#brand" title="" rel="brand">Branding</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#catalog" title="" rel="catalog">Catalog</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#id" title="" rel="id">Corporate ID</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#relations" title="" rel="relations">Consumer Relations</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#incentive" title="" rel="incentive">Incentive/Loyalty</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#packaging" title="" rel="packaging">Packaging</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#launch" title="" rel="launch">Product Launch</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#promo" title="" rel="promo">Promotion</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#public" title="" rel="public">Public Relations</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#sales" title="" rel="sales">Sales Support</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#social" title="" rel="social">Social Media</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#trade" title="" rel="trade">Tradeshows</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#web" title="" rel="web">Web/Mobile</a>

  </li>
</ul>
<div id="bottomWrapper"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7h1ontgd/1/).

Incidentally, the reason your original code didn't work, and *couldn't* work, is because of this line:

```
$(".currentFilter").replaceWith($(this).append());
```

This replaced the selected element(s) with the clicked `<a>` element, which meant that, in future, the there was no `.currentFilter` element to replace or update.

On the other hand, if you *want* to put the clicked `<a>` element into the `.currentFilter` span-element, then you could try the following approach:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".workFilterButtons a").click(function () {

        // finding those <li> elements whose text, when trimmed
        // (removing leading and trailing white-space) is equal
        // to an empty string (''):
        var emptyLi = $('.workFilterButtons').filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().trim() === '';
        }),

        // caching the '.currentFilter' element(s):
            currentFilter = $('.currentFilter'),

        // checking for those elements in the
        // currentFilter jQuery object that have
        // a descendant <a> element, and finding
        // length of that collection, and then
        // checking that it's greater than 0:
            hasA = currentFilter.has('a').length > 0;

        // appending the contents of the currentFilter
        // element into the found emptyLi element:
        emptyLi.append(currentFilter.contents());

        // if there are no <a> elements in the 
        // currentFilter element(s):
        if (!hasA) {

            // we replace the contents (textNode 'all')
            // with the clicked <a> element:
            currentFilter.contents().replaceWith(this);
        } else {
            // otherwise we append the clicked link to
            // the currentFilter; this works because
            // once we get to this stage the <a> element
            // if it exists has already been moved back
            // to the empty <li>, therefore we can't
            // use '.contents().replace()' because
            // there are no contents remaining by this point
            // (and yes, this was incredibly counter-intuitive
            // to me for quite a long time, which is why this
            // update took a while):
            currentFilter.append(this);
        }
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".workFilterButtons a").click(function() {
    var emptyLi = $('.workFilterButtons').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().trim() === '';
      }),
      currentFilter = $('.currentFilter'),
      hasA = currentFilter.has('a').length > 0;

    emptyLi.append(currentFilter.contents());

    if (!hasA) {
      currentFilter.contents().replaceWith(this);
    } else {
      currentFilter.append(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="portfolio-filter-container">
  <h2 class="workFilterSelect">FILTER OPTIONS: <span class="currentFilter">ALL</span></h2>

</div>
<ul id="portfolio-filter">
  <!--<li class="workFilterSelect">FILTER OPTIONS:</li>-->
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#all" title="all">All</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#ad" title="advertising" rel="ad">Advertising</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#brand" title="" rel="brand">Branding</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#catalog" title="" rel="catalog">Catalog</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#id" title="" rel="id">Corporate ID</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#relations" title="" rel="relations">Consumer Relations</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#incentive" title="" rel="incentive">Incentive/Loyalty</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#packaging" title="" rel="packaging">Packaging</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#launch" title="" rel="launch">Product Launch</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#promo" title="" rel="promo">Promotion</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#public" title="" rel="public">Public Relations</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#sales" title="" rel="sales">Sales Support</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#social" title="" rel="social">Social Media</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#trade" title="" rel="trade">Tradeshows</a>

  </li>
  <li class="workFilterButtons"><a href="#web" title="" rel="web">Web/Mobile</a>

  </li>
</ul>
<div id="bottomWrapper"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7h1ontgd/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/).
  - [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, hopefully I was of some small help. You might want to check the edits, because I'm not sure if you were deliberately moving the link to the title, and out of the list, or if that was just a misunderstanding. Either way, I've added a further sample of code that offers that functionality (if it's wanted) and demonstrations.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your `class="currentFilter"` to `id="currentFilter"` so now you won't need a `.each()` to do what you want to do, the selector selects only 1 element and not an array of 1 element.

Also changed `replaceWith()` with `text()`, and likewise `append()` replaced with `text()`.

Here's a fiddle if you want to see it in action
https://jsfiddle.net/s6bpwycn/

Comment: Wow thanks alot. I appreciate the explanation. This really helped me!